# Facebook API post to groups is posting on wall instead of the group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-group

I have the following publish action in my script. I am coding in PHP

```
$publish = $facebook->api('/'.$group_id.'/feed', 'post',
                    array('access_token' => $_SESSION['token'],
                    'message'=> $lrinfo['propheading'],
                    'from' => $config['App_ID'],
                    'to' => $group_id,
                    'caption' => 'Landshoppe',
                    'name' => 'Landshoppe',
                    'link' => "http://www.landshoppe.com/".$postpage,
                    'picture' => $fbimg,
                    'description' => $lrinfo['AdditionalData']
        ));
```

Somehow, the post is appearing on the account wall rather than the specified Group in which the account is a member.

Could this be an issue with the above publish query or something else ? Which other part of the API code flow should be examined ?

Comment: Judging by the structure of the request I'd look at what the `$group_id` variable actually contains.

Comment: The group_id variable has the right value....

Comment: Have you checked the documentation, what permissions are needed to post to a group feed ...?